# Laravel queue with Twitter api

Tags: php, twitter, queue, laravel-5, twitter-oauth

I'm using the thujohn/twitter package on https://github.com/thujohn/twitter to update user status posts from my site to twitter.

I want to use larvae's queues to post this function in the background. But i keep getting a failed-job. with an error:

```
exception 'Exception' with message '[220] Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.' in /home/vagrant/sites/pms/vendor/thujohn/twitter/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php:297
```

Stack trace:

my job looks like this:

```
namespace PMS\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Twitter;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostToTwitter implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $tweetLength;

public $userPage;

public $body;

//public $twitterToken;

//public $secret;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($tweetLength, $userPage, $body)
{
    $this->tweetLength = $tweetLength;
    $this->userpage = $userPage;
    $this->body = $body;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Twitter::postTweet(['status' => str_limit($this->body . $this->userpage,$this->tweetLength), 'format' => 'json']);
}
}
```

and in my controller I'm dispatching like this:

```
$this->dispatch(new PostToTwitter($tweetLength, $userPage, $body));
```

my function works fine if i run it in my controller , but if i try to dispatch it to a job, my jobs fail

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by switching to a different library, following this blog post: http://markusos.github.io/engage/2014/12/06/1000-tweets-per-week.html